# Remember Select Option

Tags: php

I have this form:

```
<form method='POST' action='update_ads.php'>
  <select size='1' name='type'>
  <OPTION value=''></OPTION>
  <OPTION value='1'>Open</OPTION>
  <OPTION value='0'>Closed</OPTION>
  </select>

  <input type='submit' value='Save'>
</form>
```

and this PHP file associated with it:

```
$id        = $_POST['id'];
$type = addslashes($_POST['type']);
$query =  mysql_query("UPDATE ads SET type='$type' where id=$id");
```

What can I add so that the option that the user choose before they clicked "submit" comes back when they re-open it? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to get the state from your database you need to provide us with its structure.
You might also considere using a framework like [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/). I think you're learning php the difficult way ;)

Comment: @John you are right i feel that my way in learning is hard and wrong :( i dont know how to start so i dont ask this dumb questions

Comment: check out [this W3C tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp) and after that [this Zend tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html).
That's gonna get you up to speed without destroying you reputation here.

Comment: thanks for the help iam gonna check it

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way:

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['id']) && ((int) $_POST['id'])) != 0) {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
    }

    //connect to db

    //get the responce of the query "SELECT `type` FROM `ads` WHERE `id` = $id"

    //put it in a variable named $type

    ?>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <select size='1' name='type'>
            <option value="" <?=($type == '') ? 'selected="selected"' : ''?>></option>
            <option value="1" <?=($type == 1) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''?>>Open</option>
            <option value="0" <?=($type == 2) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''?>>Closed</option>
        </select>
    </form>
```

Edit: This is good ony if you have a select with not many options, otherwise you should use somethink like a foreach statement.

For many options you can use this:

```
    <?php
    $options = array('Open' => 1, 'Closed' => 0, 'Select an option' => ''); ?>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <select size='1' name='type'>
        <?php
        foreach($options as $label => $option) { 
            if ($type == $option) {
                $checked = 'selected="selected"';
            }
            else {
                $checked = '';
            }
        ?>
            <option value="<?=$option?>" <?=$checked?>><?=$label?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </select>
    </form>
```

Comment: No its only 2 choice but i just need to know the method then i can see the other method ( foreach ) soon

Comment: Thanks so much for help last thing i need to know how can i get the arrays from status table in database ? 

array(1, 2, 3, 4)

become for example

array(Opened, Closed, Deleted)

Answer (score 0):

Put this form in a string ($form) and do this

```
$form = str_replace(" value='".$id."'>"," value='".$id."' selected>", $form);

echo $form;
```

You can memorize the $id in a cookie.

Comment: thanks for help but i need the status to store in database so anyone log see the same status i choose

Answer (score 0):

when the user loads the page, you have to check the database for the current selection.

then you change the html based on the selection:
`<OPTION value='1' selected='selected'>Open</OPTION>

<OPTION value='0'>Closed</OPTION>`

or

`<OPTION value='1'>Open</OPTION>

<OPTION value='0' selected='selected'>Closed</OPTION>`

by the way, your `ID` has not been set in this form. you need to escape that as well

Answer (score 0):

Not really the best solution, but it don't really know where this is going.

```
<select size="1" name="type">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1"<?= $_POST['type']==1 ? " selected" : ""?>></option>
  <option value="0"<?= $_POST['type']==0 ? " selected" : ""?>></option>
</select>
```

BTW: You might want to take a look at [this.](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2001/05/03/php_foundations.html)